# No images in popups (only URL is displayed)

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I'm trying to do a mapaweb test from Qgis 3.4, generating the same with Qgis2web. The map has popup images. In local mode, the images are seen perfectly at the point I want.

To upload to the network, I have changed in the PHOTO field of Qgis table the web address of each image and I have uploaded to the server of my website all Qgis2web folders. also, in the code of `Layers.js` and `Qgis2web.js`, I have already changed `"Photo"` to `"attachment"`, but only the web address where the image is hosted is displayed, not the image.

[image]
Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: Photos in popups have not been looked at for a little while in qgis2web. This is because of a current upstream bug in QGIS affecting the Attachment edit widget. Until this bug is fixed, it will be difficult to make much progress on this issue. Here's the QGIS bug: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19118

Comment: @TomChadwin Please post your comment as an answer so this question can be marked as answered. You're the ultimate reference for qgis2web after all :)

Comment: Didn't feel like an answer to me, but I shall do as you bid.

Comment: Since 1 year (!) the same bug. I can not use the fantastic plugin qgis2web within qgis3. 
What`s the matter, qgis programmers?

Comment: Same bug for QGIS 3.4.x with Windows 10 and QGIS 3.8.1 with Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Photos in popups have not been looked at for a little while in qgis2web. This is because of a current upstream bug in QGIS affecting the Attachment edit widget. Until this bug is fixed, it will be difficult to make much progress on this issue. Here's the QGIS bug: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19118

Comment: please wait, I am writing.....

Comment: Hello Tom,
could you please write an answer/comment to this thread within github?:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/30930
My understanding is: We could not insert images for qgis2web without this function. If this is right, please answer  m-kuhn there, that we need this function. I think, he want hear your opinion as the developer of the plugin qgis2web. Your answer has more weight.
It is possible, that I do not know if I have an alternative possibility to show the images as point-popup within qgis2web. There are any possibilty? Maybe a circuitous solution?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Update: Since QGIS 3.4.13 with qgis2web 3.10 it is POSSIBLE to show images in popups.
Thank you very much Tom Chadwin and all involved QGIS programmers.